# ASP.NET Core 7 project takes long time on first load in production

Tags: razor, razor-pages, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-7.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 Razor pages project. It works fine on localhost, but when I upload the project to my web server on the internet, the first time it loads, it takes a few seconds to load the website, however subsequent requests are fast.

Here is my `program.cs` file - is there something wrong with my code or the server?

I searched other posts on Stackoverflow other coders have the same problem but found no good solution!

```
using mywebsite.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
using mywebsite.Core.Middleware;
using Keyvan1.Utility;
using AutoMapper;
using GoogleReCaptcha.V3.Interface;
using GoogleReCaptcha.V3;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost
       .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
       .UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true");

builder.Services.Configure<CookieTempDataProviderOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "mywebsiteTempDataCookie";
});


builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);

var keysDirectoryName = "Keys";

var keysDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, keysDirectoryName);

if (!Directory.Exists(keysDirectoryPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(keysDirectoryPath);
}

builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
  .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(keysDirectoryPath))
  .SetApplicationName("mywebsite")
  .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(30));

#if DEBUG
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer("Server=(local);Database=test;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"));
#else
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
#endif

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config => {
    config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    // Password requirements
    config.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    config.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    // config.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
    config.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    config.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "mywebsite.Session";
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
});

builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(Constants.AdminRole, policy => policy.RequireRole(Constants.AdminRole));
});

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    //options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.Name = "KeyhanStore";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(2);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.LoginPath = $"/admin/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = $"/admin/Logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Areas/admin/AccessDenied";
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("Cors", builder =>
{
    builder
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    //.AllowCredentials()
    .WithHeaders("accept", "content-type", "origin")
    .AllowAnyOrigin();
}));

builder.Services.Configure<PhotoSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("PhotoSettings"));
builder.Services.Configure<EmailSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<ICaptchaValidator, GoogleReCaptchaValidator>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPhotoService, PhotoService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPhotoStorage, PhotoStorage>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailService, EmailService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IStatsRepository, StatsRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IContactRepository, ContactRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISettingRepository, SettingRepository>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IDbInitializer, DbInitializer>();


builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
Mapper.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
});

 
builder.Services.AddMvc()
             .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
             {   options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("admin", "/Products");
                 options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("admin", "/Settings");
                 options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("admin", "/Categories");
             });

var app = builder.Build();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    context.Database.Migrate();

    var dbInitializer = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDbInitializer>();
    dbInitializer.Initialize();
}

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseCors("Cors");
app.UseSecurityHeadersMiddleware(
      new SecurityHeadersBuilder()
     .AddDefaultSecurePolicy());

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
    {
        const int durationInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24;
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
            "public,max-age=" + durationInSeconds;
    }
});

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();
app.MapRazorPages();

#pragma warning disable ASP0014
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        "admin",
        "admin",
        "admin/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        "default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

});
#pragma warning restore ASP0014

app.Run();
```

I need the project to load fast on the first request

Comment: Have you managed to find out which operation is slow?

Comment: @Lajos Arpad
unfortunately not.it seems the production server is the problem.I should test it on another server

Comment: Can you benchmark your production server in order to find out exactly what is slow? It's hard to give you any advice about performance improvement without knowing what was slow.

Comment: it seems it is a  server problem.they made some changes and also some changes in web.config for caching and it loads faster now

Answer (score 0):

It's normal for the first request to suffer from a latency hit while the application loads, builds its pipeline, service container, routes etc. There are some things you can do that might minimise this a bit e.g. pre-building services (https://andrewlock.net/reducing-latency-by-pre-building-singletons-in-asp-net-core/), but you can never eliminate the issue.